# Copy-move forgery detection using sift algorithm and keypoints matching using knn

Tags: python, opencv, knn, sift

I am stuck in the keypoints matching step where my output is showing as matching two similar images by comparing them but I want output on single image showing matching lines on the forged or duplicated region. Could you please help me for this problem ? I shall be very thankful to you in this regard.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Step 1: Read the image
image_path = (r"C:\Users\mirza\OneDrive\Documents\Artificial Intelligence\human_F.png")

image = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Step 2: Convert the image to grayscale
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Step 3: Initialize the SIFT feature extractor
sift = cv2.SIFT_create()

# Step 4: Detect keypoints in the grayscale image
keypoints = sift.detect(gray_image, None)

# Step 5: Create a blank image of the same size as the original image
output_image = np.copy(image)

# Step 6: Draw red dots as keypoints on the output image
for keypoint in keypoints:
    x, y = keypoint.pt
    cv2.circle(output_image, (int(x), int(y)), 2, (0, 0, 255), -1)

# Step 7: Display or save the output image with red dots
cv2.imshow("Keypoints Image", output_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Step 8: Compute descriptors for the keypoints
keypoints, descriptors = sift.compute(gray_image, keypoints)

# Step 9: Create a BFMatcher object
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()

# Step 10: Match keypoints using 2NN (Nearest Neighbors)
matches = bf.knnMatch(descriptors, descriptors, k=2)

# Step 11: Apply Lowe's ratio test to filter out weak matches
good_matches = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance:
        good_matches.append(m)

# Step 12: Draw matching lines on the output image
matching_image = cv2.drawMatches(
    gray_image, keypoints, gray_image, keypoints, good_matches, None,
    matchColor=(0, 0, 255), flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS
)

# Step 13: Display or save the matching image
cv2.imshow("Matching Image", matching_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Step 14: Apply the Clustering-Based Filter algorithm (CBF) to filter out false matches
# You can implement the CBF algorithm based on your specific requirements

# Step 15: Perform Delaunay triangulation on the remaining keypoints to mark copy-move regions
# You can use OpenCV's Delaunay triangulation function (cv2.Subdiv2D) to achieve this

# Step 16: Display or save the final result with copy-move regions marked
# You can use OpenCV's drawing functions to draw triangles on the image to mark the regions
```